# Image type in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

Hello guys what should be the type of `Source` and `Style`

The source is going to contain the image file location. Something like this

```
source = require('../../../assets/user.png')
```

and style is going to have an Object of styles but not sure if I write `style: Object` will be right.

```
export interface AvatarProps {
    source?: any;  <<<<< Don't want to use any
    style?: any;   <<<<< Don't want to use any
    shape?: string;
    ImageComponent?: React.ComponentType;
    size?: 'tiny' | 'small' | 'medium' | 'large' | 'giant';
}

export const Avatar: FunctionComponent<AvatarProps> = ({
    shape,
    style,
    size = 'medium',
    ImageComponent,
    source = require('../../../assets/user.png'),
}) => {
    return (
        <View>
         ....
        </View>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`source` is just a string. Importing binary data is not necessary; often all we need is a URL。

For `style`, since you are using `React`, you can use `React.CSSProperties` to be its type.

Comment: Thank you `React.CSSProperties` this helps

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ImageSourcePropType` and `ImageStyle` from react-native.

```
interface AvatarProps {
  style: StyleProp<ImageStyle>;
  source: ImageSourcePropType;
}
```

For `source`, `ImageSourcePropType` will cover remote and local images

```
<MyAvatar source={{ uri: 'https://placehold.it/50x50' }} />
<MyAvatar source={require('../assets/hello-world.png} />
```

A tip: If you go into the React Native documentation, it may tell you the types. https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#source mentions type `ImageSourcePropType`

For style, https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#style it doesn't explicitly mention the type, however, if you are using VSCode and you hover over a prop, it'll reveal its desired type.
[image: A screenshot of a User hovering over a prop and the type being revealed in VSCode]

If hovering doesn't work, command (⌘) and click the prop, and it'll show you the desired type.

```
export interface ImageProps extends ImagePropsBase {
    /**
     *
     * Style
     */
    style?: StyleProp<ImageStyle>;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A file location is just a string, so the type of `source` would be `string`. For `style`, it depends. If it's an object you think is going to be re-used or extended, its better to create an interface and use that type. Try to take advantage of the typing system by avoiding general types such as `object`.

Comment: you're welcome. If you are pleased with the answer you can click on the checkmark.